# Como mudar o separador de campos de arquivos CSV de ',' para ';'

Tags: csv, xls

estou desenvolvendo um utilitário para transformar arquivos XLS e XLSX para CSV, porém gostaria que os arquivos CSV saíssem com separador ponto e vírgula ao invés de vírgula, eis o código:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import glob
import pandas as pd

excel_files = glob.glob('D:\Conversao de Dados\Central de 
Utilitarios\PROJETOS\XLS2CSV\excel\*.xlsx') # caminho dos arquivos excel

for excel in excel_files:
    out = excel.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel) # converte apenas 1 folha por arquivo
    df.to_csv(out)
```

Grande parte do código não é de minha autoria e eu não sou experiente em Python, se alguém puder me ajudar, ficaria muito grato...

Comment: Por favor, veja a documentação de [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: uma forma simples de se fazer isso é escrever no começo do arquivo sep=;

Comment: sendo o ; o tipo de separador que voce quiser, podendo ser qualquer outra coisa exemplo: sep=|

Comment: Consegui pessoal, obrigado pela ajuda... bastou colocar o sep = ';' após o out na última linha

                  df.to_csv(out, sep=';')